Telecom Lines Conducted emissions
We have rented a Telecom line ISN to conduct some in-house pre-compliance testing. The test setup closely follows the CISPR32 standard. We encountered issues with conducted emissions in the lab, which necessitated the rental.
We have a device that is PoE powered, the PoE interfacing is done using a TPS23751 chip. The operating frequency of the chip is set to 264kHz.
During our in-house testing, I tried two configurations:
The unit floating with the chassis not connected to ground - Blue trace
The chassis connected to the ground plane - Yellow trace
The test results are as follows:

What could be the reason for the unit to be quieter when ungrounded?

Noise on the ground? Common-mode noise? Line acting as tuned circuit?

Wouldn't the chasi drive the noise to ground? When unit is floating where will the noise be going?

Where do you ground it? There is no diagram or schematic or anything, not even what ground you mean and how does Ethernet connection and PoE fits there. There are strict PoE isolation requirements.
